# How can I use string argument input as a variable name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I use string argument input as a part of variable name in a Javascript? I want to do that because it seems to be tedious to define getter and setter for all the fields... while most of the fields have similar names.

For example,

```
var random = {
    this.input1_field : null,
    this.input2_field : null,
    set: function(name,field){
       this.name_field = field;   
    }
}
```

where I want name_field to be dynamic based on the input variable 'name'. (ex, name="input1" or name="input2" etc)

Comment: I don't think you can write `this.input1_field` like that. Surely that's a syntax error?  And why to you want to define a getter and a setter? Sounds like a bad habit coming from Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this[name + "_field"] = field`

You can just pass in a string and use it.

`this["input1_field"] === this.input1_field`

Answer (score 1):

If your variable has been declared as global, you could do something like this:

```
var myVar = 5;
var myString = "myVar";

function anyFunc(str){
    return window[str];
}

anyFunc(myString); // Outputs 5
```

If this variable is local, you could follow the same procedure using the pointer `this` instead of `window`.